# Neo4j data in front end like html

Tags: javascript, html, neo4j

I have some nodes created in my neo4j that is located on a server. I want to know if it is possible for me to show those nodes on a html page. Which language would be the most preferable for doing this.

Comment: check the https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/... also neo4j browser is open source, you can try to implement it yourself https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing nodes from your neo4j server is certainly possible. In fact, I'm working on a project right now that is incorporating this. I am using JavaScript, but I believe neo4j supports many other languages such as Java and Python.

For me, JavaScript is the easiest. Neo4j also officially supports this. There is a neo4j-js driver available from neo4j's website here.

http://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/

I am sure you will be able to understand the documentation that neo4j provides there. I had little to no knowledge of the driver a few days ago, but that documentation helped me understand how to use JavaScript to access neo4j.

Also, here is an example from neo4j that I think may be beneficial to you.

https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-javascript-bolt